# fql bug: page_id is greater that max int value

Tags: select, facebook-fql, facebook-page, integer

The developers of facebook states that page_id in the page table is integer.

But because of many facebook pages, it number increased greater that max int value

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

so the fql's select gives smth like this e+123213

Comment: Are you facing this problem or are you pointing out a bug in fql?

Comment: i faced with a real estate bug, which gives me wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in [`page` table documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/). In Graph API [documentation for `page` object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) refer to this field as `string`.

It's actually better to save/use any `id` returned by Facebook as `string` since in many cases  value of `id` will cause overflow over `integer` boundaries. And for some objects `id` may contain characters other that numbers (underscore).

**Update:**
To clarify some things. The issue is really not only with documentation but with return data too. API return response as JSON (or if you using old REST API you can specify XML format too) `string`. So the response do contain full and correct `page_id`, but in the phase of JSON parsing you loose it due to fact that it's parsed as `integer`.

In PHP 5.4 [`json_decode` function](http://il.php.net/json_decode) have additional `options` parameter which may be `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` to overcome this issue. You should check if the parsing method you use supports something like this.

There is couple of bugs opened for this issue on Facebook (it's not for the `page_id` in `page` table, but same behavior for `uid` field on other tables):

- [UID's treated as integers for FQL queries in PHP SDK and exceed PHP_INT_MAX on 32-bit systems](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/268511109886124)
- [Invalid uid format when fetching FQL page_fan table with fql via GRAPH api](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/201677409928555)

Actually you can do something to overcome this issue:

- If you using PHP you may either:

  - use 64bit version of run-time which have no this issue due to bigger `PHP_INT_MAX`
  - use PHP 5.4 with `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` option passed to `json_decode`
- If you using PHP or any other technology:

  - use alternative JSON parser (I'm not aware of any JSON parser in PHP that able to handle this)
  - Use quick and dirty reqular expression to wrap all numbers in response with quotes `$response = preg_replace('/(\b\d+\b)/', '"$1"', $response)` (this is for PHP, but you'll get the idea)

Also I recommend filing additional Bug on Facebook and updating your question so we can subscribe to it as well.

Comment: the problem is not in documentation, fql table returns it as integer, and because the value is greater that max int, it converts it into some sort of e+4234234

Comment: @Aziz, I've added clarifications and details on issue which you may find useful ;)